# gitlab runner docker executor - config.toml feature flags issue

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I've registered a gitlab-runner with a docker executor for our group
on a self-hosted Gitlab 15.7.6 CE.
When I try to set the following feature flags for the runner (as per [gitlab-ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/15.7/runner/configuration/feature-flags.html#enable-feature-flag-in-runner-configuration)) I get the following error:

```
FATAL: toml: cannot load TOML value of type string into a Go boolean
```

or

```
FATAL: toml: cannot load TOML value of type int64 into a Go boolean
```

Below the config.toml in place:

```
concurrent = 4
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "Docker executor runner"
  url = "..."
  id = 2963
  token = "...."
  token_obtained_at = 2023-02-23T12:11:19Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.feature_flags]
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD = true
    FF_USE_FASTZIP = true
    ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL = "fast"
    CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL = "fast"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:20.04"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    allowed_pull_policies = ["always", "if-not-present"]
```

I can't find what wrong- since both 1 or true are accepted values for the flags.

Comment: Probably an error in the order of definition of the block, as per this other issue: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/using-runners-docker-tmpfs-throws-cannot-load-toml-value-of-type-bool-into-a-go-string/70896. Since your are activating the cache as a feature flag, I would move the cache definition upper the feature flag one?

Comment: I didn't change the error being returned